# WCF REST POST Service - Method not allowed when calling from HTML FORM

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Suddenly I'm getting an error 'Method not allowed.' when calling a WCF REST POST Service from a HTML Form as below (It was working earlier in Development, UAT, Production environments, but is now failing.

What could have caused this issue? and what is a potential fix ?

```
<form action="http://localhost:8750/MyService/MyEmailService/RecordResponse" method="post" runat="server">
    <div align="left">
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="abc">
        <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="625">
        <select name="response">
            <option value="Approved">Approve</option>
            <option value="Rejected">Reject</option>
        </select>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="comment">Add comments here</textarea>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class MyEmailService: IMyEmailService, ISessionAwareService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/RecordResponse", Method = "POST")]
    public void RecordResponse(Stream stream)
    { 
        // My business logic
    }
}
```

The configuration is as follows:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webby">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>

  <service name="CTRL.Server.CommandHandlerService.EmailHandlerService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8750/MyService/MyEmailService" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="MyService.ServiceContracts.IEmailService" 
              behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secure">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a background, we generate email with HTML programmatically with form whose action was calling the WCF REST service on submit of html form.

The email client was outlook where users used to read emails.

There was some infrastructure upgrade and on submitting the html form somehow POST request for WCF was not getting generated properly.

To resolve this issue, we modified the WCF service from POST to GET, wrote a Javascript method to get the form data and call the WCF service by inclusing the html form data in WCF REST service URI.